# xamarin access protected firebase realtime database with nuget package FirebaseAuthentication.net

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

im beginner in firebase and im using two nuget packages FirebaseAuthentication.net and FirebaseDatabase.net . im trying to write to a protected firebase realtime database that has a rule that look like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i randomly tryed SignInWithOAuthAsync method however it throws an Exception `[ mail auth type connot be used like this. use method specifc to email & password authentication]`

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(webApiKey));
                var savedfirebaseauth = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirebaseAuth>(Preferences.Get("MyFirebaseRefreshToken", ""));
                await authProvider.SignInWithOAuthAsync(FirebaseAuthType.EmailAndPassword, savedfirebaseauth.FirebaseToken);
                

                //inserting info into the database
               
                await firebaseClient.Child("users").Child("some uid1").PutAsync(new userinfo
                {

                    firstName = "dtox",
                    secondName = "solo"
                });

                //clear the entry
                recordData.Text = "";

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }
```

pleace let me know if my question needs more Clarificatio thanks in advance.
[mr Frank van](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)

Comment: is that the **exact** error message you get?  What is the exception type?

Comment: im using try and catch and this is what i see without try and catch the app just crashes

Comment: if you are catching the exception then you should be able to see the type.  The error message is generating ZERO google hits which is generally a sign that it's not a verbatim copy of the error

Comment: i run the program without catching and this is what i see [System.InvalidOperationException: 'Email auth type cannot be used like this. Use methods specific to email & password authentication.']

Comment: looks like that is not a valid option: https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet/blob/7fc2859ff6b641ec9efd1d552d2c4390e3699766/src/Firebase.Auth/FirebaseAuthProvider.cs#L695

Comment: i dont undrstand what should i do? how can i fix this?

Comment: what auth provider are you using?

Comment: you can see the whole code infront of you if i im missing somthing pleace tell me

Comment: guys anybody....?  this  is my first question on stackoverflow and i didnt get an answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

dont worry i got you

```
//first you need to authenticate before writtng to your database
var auth = await authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(your email, your password);
                var firebaseClientt = new FirebaseClient(
                  "your url ",
                  new FirebaseOptions
                  {
                      AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(auth.FirebaseToken)
                  });
//now you can write to your database
 await firebaseClientt.Child("users").Child("some uid").PutAsync(new userinfo
                {

                    firstName = "dtox",
                    secondName = "solo"
                });
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked i have been struggling with this for days thank you so much mr noor